# Vertically center aligned image in a table row (wikisyntax)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align contents of a one row table. While the text seems to have been center aligned, the image refuses to do so.

Code for table (uses wikisyntax!)

```
{| class="mp-left" style="background:#FFFFE0;"
! style="background:#FFDEAD; border:1px solid #EECFA1; border-right:0px; padding:0px; vertical-align:left; font-weight:normal; width:100%;" | <H3 class="mp">  <div style="float:left;">[[चित्र:Golden wikipedia featured star.svg|25px|alt=|link=]]</div>Featured Article</H3>
! style="background:#FFDEAD; border:1px solid #EECFA1; border-left:0px; padding:0px; vertical-align:middle;" | <div style="float:right;">[[File:Wikibar.png|90px|alt=|link=]]</div>
|}
```

CSS:

```
table.mp-left, table.mp-right {
vertical-align:top;
border-spacing: 0px;
}

h3.mp {
float:left;
margin-top: 0pt !important;/* Needed across browsers */
margin-bottom: 0pt !important;/* Needed across browsers */
padding-top: 0pt;
padding-bottom: 5pt;
padding-right: 1em;/* Needed for opera and safari on windows 7 */
padding-left: 5pt;
}
```

See:
[image: Orange globe is not v aligned]

Comment: Can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: (pt or `px`) also use `margin-top: -4px;`

Comment: Apply inline-block to imagd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
table.mp-left td{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to help either!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fiddle can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/xmJ3R/3/

here is the css:

```
* {padding:0;margin:0;}

body{padding:20px;}

.ctn {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-ctn {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3%;
    max-width: 120px;
    background: #cecece;
    font-size: 0;
}

.img-ctn > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsoLY17fqlLnsh_Pc0I4lpxAOcjmKHre1usiKdv0v3JYvibkSG1jo3PiM" />
            <span>Some Text here!</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    border:1px solid black;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: .5em 0;
}
```

I put it into a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xasip/1/).

Obviously, you would need to adapt to your needs.